# How do I repair a trackpad/touchpad that has lost it's click?

Tags: mac, touchpad, hardware-failure, macbook-air

I have a current generation MacBook Air (11.6"). The trackpad no longer mechanically clicks. It moves a bit and registers the click, but doesn't click. Possibly related to resting a hot cup of coffee on the case. Is there any way of fixing it, with or without T5s? Or is it a get Apple to fix it/live with it?

Comment: I switch on the "tap to click" option (under Apple > System Preferences... > Trackpad) for a week. But now it has fixed itself as if  by magic. Crumbs?

Comment: It went bad again. After I had my screen replaced it came back working but not well enough for me to switch back from tap-to-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this situation happened to me on my last mac and the only solution I found was to basically change the trackpad itself. Because I was not on warranty, I went on [ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-MacBook-Unibody-Model-A1342-Upper-Case-Replacement/2185/1), purchased a new one and changed it. Not an easy task but it fixed my problem...

If you prefer you can always "genius bar" this situation... but it will be more expensive.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you **do not** need to replace the trackpad!

When you remove the bottom cover by using a pentalobe 1.2 screwdriver, you will realize that there is a screw in the middle of the area between the trackpad and the edge of the computer. It is a small philips screw. You probably need to loosen that one. Not too much though, because it might stop registering the clicks. Sometime 1/4 of a full rotation might work. You will need to experiment with this.

Moreover, when you are putting the bottom cover back, the amount of tightness applied to the outer screws will have an affect on how it is going to work. You also need to optimize the tightening level in those screws.

Answer (score 1):

also i noticed that a bad battery can cause this problem, if you remove the back cover and the battery see if the back of the battery (the one that is directly in contact with your trackpad) is flat as it should be and without any bump. I fixed mine just pressing (gently) the bumps in the back of the battery. And of course if this is the case buy a new battery!.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though this is a mechanical/space related problem.  So, I figure, maybe if I "create space" by gently pushing down on my trackpad the problem will be fixed.  Voilà: all but the left upper corner now clicks normally.

A crude fix to be sure, but a fix none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had spilled some coffee on track pad and it was not clicking the next day.
I switched the lap top off, I spray a little  computer screen cleaner along the edges of the track pad and then took a paper and by gently pushing down the track pad on the edges cleaned the circumference. Cleaned the residue with a tissue paper and now the track pad clicks. So need to open the mac air from back, try this first and if it works it will save you time ! cheers